# Facebook SDK exception catch error but return null

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am new on this field, so sorry for any mistake that I made

I have create a website that using facebook login by facebook php sdk.
I have tested on my localhost, it work fine, but when I upload to the real server on internet. It catch the facebook sdk exception, but the exception return null.
I don't know how to check it, because on my wamp server everything work fine.

This is my login code.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/Facebook/autoload.php';        
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => '?',
'app_secret' => '?',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
]); 
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();        
$permissions = ['email','public_profile','user_likes']; // Optional permissions
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://example.com/logincallback.php', $permissions);
echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($loginUrl) . '"><img src="../images/system/fbround.png" width="50" height="50" /></a>';
```

This is my redirect page.

```
include("config.php");
require_once __DIR__. '/pages/Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '?',  
  'app_secret' => '?',  
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',  
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();  

try {  
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();  
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {  
  // When Graph returns an error  
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();  
  exit;  
} 
catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {  
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
  exit;  
}  

if (! isset($accessToken)) {  
  if ($helper->getError()) {  
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');  
    echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
    echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
    echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
    echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
  } else {  
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');  
    echo 'Bad request';  
  }  
  exit;  
}

// The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens  
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();  

// Get the access token metadata from /debug_token  
$tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);

$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email', $accessToken->getValue());

$user = $response->getGraphUser();



$_SESSION['user_fbid']=$user['id'];
$_SESSION['user_email']=$user['email'];
$_SESSION['user_fullname']=$user['name'];
$_SESSION['accesstoken']=(string) $accessToken;
$_SESSION['facebooklogin']='1';

// Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException's when they fail)  
$tokenMetadata->validateAppId('1501129246877759');  
// If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate it here  
// $tokenMetadata->validateUserId('123');  
$tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();   

if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {  
// Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one  
try {  
  $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);  
} catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {  
  echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $helper->getMessage() . "</p>";  
  exit;  
} 
  echo '<h3>Long-lived</h3>';  
  var_dump($accessToken->getValue());  
}

header('Location: http://example.com');
```

I got this code for documentation on facebook app.
I have enable php_curl extension and php_mbstring extension on my online server
but it always return exception error with the description.

this is the error:

```
Facebook SDK returned an error:
```

I don't now why it doesn't work on my online server. but it work perfectly on my wamp server.

This is the exception that have been catch

```
object(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException)#14 (7) { ["message":protected]=> string(0) "" ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=> int(7) ["file":protected]=> string(74) "/home/www/yeaksa.com/pages/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php" ["line":protected]=> int(83) ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(6) { [0]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(54) "/home/www/yeaksa.com/pages/Facebook/FacebookClient.php" ["line"]=> int(216) ["function"]=> string(4) "send" ["class"]=> string(43) "Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(1029) "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/oauth/access_token?code=AQA1pHyXLTD8BIkpNG8gd60h0kI2I0uJpKS5KOtwSZPU0Ak1H_a0_cXaORNasnKmXRHTSqBngUGepiTEwmPMvHsbGRku53SXI6t0oPXIjMdR8JAwPyuozltmaKfg_UZ6zeCVJrnPDsoBvFoznY4tQqSUQw-81fbvUui9kSVhJQhtRIlUrNE4vhd23EPNv0454enY4H3K2waGFtcg4qolyAGLOXqn6szOJj2HHZkUkqlvqaBchkvu55154aX5sp35cENjLgWcTFgRiGSHzcH20nQX_EOoHq5D5q6VCsT1OAFSq0DCIk3_nxDFvP1vl4T1kq99SegDVe-OPhBIAOLyMcxu&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fyeaksa.com%2Flogincallback.php%3Fcode%3DAQA1pHyXLTD8BIkpNG8gd60h0kI2I0uJpKS5KOtwSZPU0Ak1H_a0_cXaORNasnKmXRHTSqBngUGepiTEwmPMvHsbGRku53SXI6t0oPXIjMdR8JAwPyuozltmaKfg_UZ6zeCVJrnPDsoBvFoznY4tQqSUQw-81fbvUui9kSVhJQhtRIlUrNE4vhd23EPNv0454enY4H3K2waGFtcg4qolyAGLOXqn6szOJj2HHZkUkqlvqaBchkvu55154aX5sp35cENjLgWcTFgRiGSHzcH20nQX_EOoHq5D5q6VCsT1OAFSq0DCIk3_nxDFvP1vl4T1kq99SegDVe-OPhBIAOLyMcxu&client_id=171845566490390&client_secret=444cd426e0262bcf9c5c0c8fe34b4e7a&access_token=171845566490390%7C444cd426e0262bcf9c5c0c8fe34b4e7a&appsecret_proof=fcac56612f51e2c41a4b07c2f7746035c7dfe29e2542225b8a804ae33845aa62" [1]=> string(3) "GET" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> array(3) { ["Content-Type"]=> string(33) "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ["User-Agent"]=> string(12) "fb-php-5.0.0" ["Accept-Encoding"]=> string(1) "*" } [4]=> int(60) } } [1]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(67) "/home/www/yeaksa.com/pages/Facebook/Authentication/OAuth2Client.php" ["line"]=> int(277) ["function"]=> string(11) "sendRequest" ["class"]=> string(23) "Facebook\FacebookClient" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(Facebook\FacebookRequest)#13 (9) { ["app":protected]=> object(Facebook\FacebookApp)#3 (2) { ["id":protected]=> string(15) "171845566490390" ["secret":protected]=> string(32) "444cd426e0262bcf9c5c0c8fe34b4e7a" } ["accessToken":protected]=> string(48) "171845566490390|444cd426e0262bcf9c5c0c8fe34b4e7a" ["method":protected]=> string(3) "GET" ["endpoint":protected]=> string(19) "/oauth/access_token" ["headers":protected]=> array(1) { ["Content-Type"]=> string(33) "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" } ["params":protected]=> array(4) { ["code"]=> string(344) "AQA1pHyXLTD8BIkpNG8gd60h0kI2I0uJpKS5KOtwSZPU0Ak1H_a0_cXaORNasnKmXRHTSqBngUGepiTEwmPMvHsbGRku53SXI6t0oPXIjMdR8JAwPyuozltmaKfg_UZ6zeCVJrnPDsoBvFoznY4tQqSUQw-81fbvUui9kSVhJQhtRIlUrNE4vhd23EPNv0454enY4H3K2waGFtcg4qolyAGLOXqn6szOJj2HHZkUkqlvqaBchkvu55154aX5sp35cENjLgWcTFgRiGSHzcH20nQX_EOoHq5D5q6VCsT1OAFSq0DCIk3_nxDFvP1vl4T1kq99SegDVe-OPhBIAOLyMcxu" ["redirect_uri"]=> string(385) "http://yeaksa.com/logincallback.php?code=AQA1pHyXLTD8BIkpNG8gd60h0kI2I0uJpKS5KOtwSZPU0Ak1H_a0_cXaORNasnKmXRHTSqBngUGepiTEwmPMvHsbGRku53SXI6t0oPXIjMdR8JAwPyuozltmaKfg_UZ6zeCVJrnPDsoBvFoznY4tQqSUQw-81fbvUui9kSVhJQhtRIlUrNE4vhd23EPNv0454enY4H3K2waGFtcg4qolyAGLOXqn6szOJj2HHZkUkqlvqaBchkvu55154aX5sp35cENjLgWcTFgRiGSHzcH20nQX_EOoHq5D5q6VCsT1OAFSq0DCIk3_nxDFvP1vl4T1kq99SegDVe-OPhBIAOLyMcxu" ["client_id"]=> string(15) "171845566490390" ["client_secret"]=> string(32) "444cd426e0262bcf9c5c0c8fe34b4e7a" } ["files":protected]=> array(0) { } ["eTag":protected]=> NULL ["graphVersion":protected]=> string(4) "v2.4" } } } [2]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(67) "/home/www/yeaksa.com/pages/Facebook/Authentication/OAuth2Client.php" ["line"]=> int(226) ["function"]=> string(27) "sendRequestWithClientParams" ["class"]=> string(36) "Facebook\Authentication\OAuth2Client" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(19) "/oauth/access_token" [1]=> array(2) { ["code"]=> string(344) "AQA1pHyXLTD8BIkpNG8gd60h0kI2I0uJpKS5KOtwSZPU0Ak1H_a0_cXaORNasnKmXRHTSqBngUGepiTEwmPMvHsbGRku53SXI6t0oPXIjMdR8JAwPyuozltmaKfg_UZ6zeCVJrnPDsoBvFoznY4tQqSUQw-81fbvUui9kSVhJQhtRIlUrNE4vhd23EPNv0454enY4H3K2waGFtcg4qolyAGLOXqn6szOJj2HHZkUkqlvqaBchkvu55154aX5sp35cENjLgWcTFgRiGSHzcH20nQX_EOoHq5D5q6VCsT1OAFSq0DCIk3_nxDFvP1vl4T1kq99SegDVe-OPhBIAOLyMcxu" ["redirect_uri"]=> string(385) "http://yeaksa.com/logincallback.php?code=AQA1pHyXLTD8BIkpNG8gd60h0kI2I0uJpKS5KOtwSZPU0Ak1H_a0_cXaORNasnKmXRHTSqBngUGepiTEwmPMvHsbGRku53SXI6t0oPXIjMdR8JAwPyuozltmaKfg_UZ6zeCVJrnPDsoBvFoznY4tQqSUQw-81fbvUui9kSVhJQhtRIlUrNE4vhd23EPNv0454enY4H3K2waGFtcg4qolyAGLOXqn6szOJj2HHZkUkqlvqaBchkvu55154aX5sp35cENjLgWcTFgRiGSHzcH20nQX_EOoHq5D5q6VCsT1OAFSq0DCIk3_nxDFvP1vl4T1kq99SegDVe-OPhBIAOLyMcxu" } } } [3]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(67) "/home/www/yeaksa.com/pages/Facebook/Authentication/OAuth2Client.php" ["line"]=> int(166) ["function"]=> string(20) "requestAnAccessToken" ["class"]=> string(36) "Facebook\Authentication\OAuth2Client" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["code"]=> string(344) "AQA1pHyXLTD8BIkpNG8gd60h0kI2I0uJpKS5KOtwSZPU0Ak1H_a0_cXaORNasnKmXRHTSqBngUGepiTEwmPMvHsbGRku53SXI6t0oPXIjMdR8JAwPyuozltmaKfg_UZ6zeCVJrnPDsoBvFoznY4tQqSUQw-81fbvUui9kSVhJQhtRIlUrNE4vhd23EPNv0454enY4H3K2waGFtcg4qolyAGLOXqn6szOJj2HHZkUkqlvqaBchkvu55154aX5sp35cENjLgWcTFgRiGSHzcH20nQX_EOoHq5D5q6VCsT1OAFSq0DCIk3_nxDFvP1vl4T1kq99SegDVe-OPhBIAOLyMcxu" ["redirect_uri"]=> string(385) "http://yeaksa.com/logincallback.php?code=AQA1pHyXLTD8BIkpNG8gd60h0kI2I0uJpKS5KOtwSZPU0Ak1H_a0_cXaORNasnKmXRHTSqBngUGepiTEwmPMvHsbGRku53SXI6t0oPXIjMdR8JAwPyuozltmaKfg_UZ6zeCVJrnPDsoBvFoznY4tQqSUQw-81fbvUui9kSVhJQhtRIlUrNE4vhd23EPNv0454enY4H3K2waGFtcg4qolyAGLOXqn6szOJj2HHZkUkqlvqaBchkvu55154aX5sp35cENjLgWcTFgRiGSHzcH20nQX_EOoHq5D5q6VCsT1OAFSq0DCIk3_nxDFvP1vl4T1kq99SegDVe-OPhBIAOLyMcxu" } } } [4]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(75) "/home/www/yeaksa.com/pages/Facebook/Helpers/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php" ["line"]=> int(255) ["function"]=> string(22) "getAccessTokenFromCode" ["class"]=> string(36) "Facebook\Authentication\OAuth2Client" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(344) "AQA1pHyXLTD8BIkpNG8gd60h0kI2I0uJpKS5KOtwSZPU0Ak1H_a0_cXaORNasnKmXRHTSqBngUGepiTEwmPMvHsbGRku53SXI6t0oPXIjMdR8JAwPyuozltmaKfg_UZ6zeCVJrnPDsoBvFoznY4tQqSUQw-81fbvUui9kSVhJQhtRIlUrNE4vhd23EPNv0454enY4H3K2waGFtcg4qolyAGLOXqn6szOJj2HHZkUkqlvqaBchkvu55154aX5sp35cENjLgWcTFgRiGSHzcH20nQX_EOoHq5D5q6VCsT1OAFSq0DCIk3_nxDFvP1vl4T1kq99SegDVe-OPhBIAOLyMcxu" [1]=> string(385) "http://yeaksa.com/logincallback.php?code=AQA1pHyXLTD8BIkpNG8gd60h0kI2I0uJpKS5KOtwSZPU0Ak1H_a0_cXaORNasnKmXRHTSqBngUGepiTEwmPMvHsbGRku53SXI6t0oPXIjMdR8JAwPyuozltmaKfg_UZ6zeCVJrnPDsoBvFoznY4tQqSUQw-81fbvUui9kSVhJQhtRIlUrNE4vhd23EPNv0454enY4H3K2waGFtcg4qolyAGLOXqn6szOJj2HHZkUkqlvqaBchkvu55154aX5sp35cENjLgWcTFgRiGSHzcH20nQX_EOoHq5D5q6VCsT1OAFSq0DCIk3_nxDFvP1vl4T1kq99SegDVe-OPhBIAOLyMcxu" } } [5]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(38) "/home/www/yeaksa.com/logincallback.php" ["line"]=> int(15) ["function"]=> string(14) "getAccessToken" ["class"]=> string(44) "Facebook\Helpers\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(0) { } } } ["previous":"Exception":private]=> NULL }
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you just exposed your app secret here (in the exception debug output), the very first thing you **must** do now is go to your app dashboard, and reset it.

Comment: thanks, you have any idea why it turn out like that.

Comment: Try enabling all errors on the server for debugging, e.g. error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", "on");